# Source switch between two batteries

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I've found several answers on switching between an Adapter and a Battery.
But I need to autmoatically switch between two batteries. One of them is 'hotplugable'.

**Problem:**
I've got a Solarcell which charges a ~16000mAh Li-Ion battery (BATa). Once in a while, the Solarcell doesn't manage to charge the battery enough. It's crucial that I have 3.0 to 4.1 Volts on my VSYS but the voltage will drop below this value if the Solarcell wasn't able to do its job (cloudy weather, vulcano eruption [joke], dirty cells, etc).

**My Plan:** I've come up with the idea to feed the VSYS with a additional, hotplugable backup battery (BATb) which does get connected to VSYS if BATa drops below ~3.1v.

So basically I need a Low-Voltage-Cutoff (using a Z-Diode with a Mosfet?) which, when cutoff happens, opens another Mosfet..?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP6HR5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**I'm not sure about the selection of M2** and how to wire it, so it will be conductive if M1 won't forward power anymore.

And I know about another electrical problem: Just using a Z-Diode (D1) with M1 will render M1 to something like a resistor, not a switch.
I've read, that I could use something like a **Shut Reference (i.e. TI's TL43xx)**. Again I'm not sure how to chose the correct one and how to wire it.

Answer (score 1):

There are chips that will do this. Linear Technology make at least one. Anyway, the problems with your circuit: -

- The diodes will drop maybe 0.4 volts to 1 volt (diode dependant and load dependant) so you are making the problem even worse using this technique.
- Even if you could find zero volt drop diodes (hint: as rare as unobtanium) the MOSFETs aren't really bringing anything to the party because the diodes would "sort out" which power supply is the "winner" based on highest voltage.
- If the mosfets were a good idea (which they don't appear to be) the gate voltage has to rise above a the source voltage by a few volts to adequately turn it on and, given the source is at 4.1 volts, it's unlikely but that's what the hot swap controller chips do - they have an internal oscillator and voltage shifter that produces an internal supply that is significantly higher than the incoming battery voltage.

So, my advice is look for hot-swap controller chips. Here's the sort of thing I mean: -

[image]

And here's another: -

[image]

There will be logic pins on these controllers that allow the use of an external voltage comparator so that when one power supply drops to a certain limit, the other power supply can take over.

Comment: I like both Chips. Both can manage exactly what I want. I wonder why I wasnt able to finde one by myself. I'll Mark your answer as correct if I have the circuit sone and tested :)

Comment: "sone" - I don't understand?

Comment: typo! That was supposed to be a "done".

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to switch between the batteries??
Why not just run from the highest voltage battery if they are in different states of charge.....or run from both when/if they eventually reach the same terminal voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ8A9Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thing is: Voltage drop and the requirement. It first **has to** deplet BATa before touching BATb. BATa has 20400mAh and BATb 460000mAh. I wouldnt want to parallel them either.